# Proving formal power series $A(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ with $A'(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, inverse

To the formal power series $A(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ with the multiplicative inverse $A^{-1}(x)$ we define $A'(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n$

How can one prove

$$(A^{-1})'(x) = - \frac{A'(x)}{A^2(x)}$$

I know that the statement is equivalent to $(A^{-1})(x)A(x) + A'(x)A^{-1}(x) = 0$

Since $A^{-1}(x)$ is the multiplicative inverse of $A$ it follows that for all $x$: $A(x) A^{-1}(x) = 1$

If we derive both sides to x (with using the product rule on the left side), then the equivalent statement is proven I think?

But how do I continue?

Comment: Differentiate by product rule and solve for $(A^{-1})'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating $$A(x)A^{-1}(x)=1$$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
A^{\prime}(x)A^{-1}(x)+A(x)\left(A^{-1}(x)\right)^{\prime}=0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(A^{-1}(x)\right)^{\prime}}&=-\frac{A^{\prime}(x)A^{-1}(x)}{A(x)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{A^{\prime}(x)}{A^2(x)}}
> \end{align*}
>
> The last step follows since $A^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{A(x)}$.